# Tutorials for cs5.5 + starling

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I buy some 2d vectors , backgrounds , enemies , heroes and platforms.
i make already a game for android with adobe cs5.5 but i have some lag and gravity issues.
So, i decide to make it again from the start using starling.
The way i draw my game is simple.I like to have my enemies , coins etc to the stage and not dynamically add them.
So , is there a good tutorial for me to explain gravity , hit collision with ground and enemies?

Also i would like to know if writing a code in timeline or in classes is better or its not a big deal if the code is good written.
Thanks!

Comment: https://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/physics-for-starling

Comment: 2D physics engine for Starling: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/citrus/physics Then, I hate to say this, but if you have to ask which is better, frame scripts or classes, you need to take some time and learn good coding practices with AS3 and OOP. For if you don't you'll just end up with a sad mess of un-refactorable code, memory leaks, bad performance, and so on. Working with Starling expects the developer to already be on a good level with AS3 and OOP.